# On click, animate the div element to the top and make it sticky

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a parent div, that contains multiple child divs inside it, On clicking any child element,I am trying to animate that child element from its current position to the top position according to its current parent, then after moving to the top with proper animation, I want that child element to be sticky, so that other child elements can be easily scrolled underneath it and then, if any other child element is clicked then it will animate to top and the recent child element will move back to its old position.

[image: Sample Image]

Any help using angular and/or html and css will be really appreciative. 
I am also attaching stackblitz angular project link for my initial code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-abbnjo

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find this question interesting, so I did a quick sample of how you can do this via jQuery. There are certainly libraries there that probably does this already, but with the interest of sharing the logic behind it, here's a quick demo in JSFiddle. It may need some more love though.

I hope this helps!

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/qo6x42za/1/

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="sticky"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" data-order="1">Box1</div>
    <div class="box" data-order="2">Box2</div>
    <div class="box" data-order="3">Box3</div>
    <div class="box" data-order="4">Box4</div>
    <div class="box" data-order="5">Box5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c90000;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$('.box').each(function(index) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        const target = $(this);
        const sticky = $('.sticky');
        const container = $('.container');
        const position = $(sticky).position();

        // after animation completes
        const options = {
            complete: () => {

                // detach previous item from sticky container and place back to original position
                if ($(sticky).children().length > 0) {
                    const firstChild = $(sticky).children().first();
                    const order = $(firstChild).data('order');
                            const previousChild = order - 1;

                    if (order > 1) {
                        $(firstChild).detach().insertAfter($(`[data-order=${previousChild}]`));
                    } else {
                        $(firstChild).detach();
                        $(container).prepend($(firstChild));
                    }
                }

                // attach item to sticky container
                $(sticky).append($(target));
                // remove the style attribute as we no longer need it
                $(target).removeAttr('style');
            }
        };

        // animate to position
        $(target).css({ position: 'absolute'});
        $(target).animate({
            top: position.top
        }, options);

    });
})
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response, that was really helpful, another thing i wanted that, child element should be sticky after reaching at the top, so that if we scroll, other elements can be scrolled underneath it easily.

Comment: also I noticed, when I click on any other element it, then the recent clicked element dose not move back to its old position.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch the moving back to old position. That can definitely be done. You are trying multiple stuffs here. I did one of the solutions only.

Comment: @AkmalRasool updated it to include the sticky header and place back items to list. Hope that helps!